# How to use configuration application block of enterprise library?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of activity code and full name which is placed in web.config file.
But now they are increased to a large number. So I want to remove that from config file and to create a db and access it with help of configuration application block.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a App.Config file.

Add the `connectionstring` to the `configuration`

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionstringname"
         connectionString="server=localhost;user id=your_bd_userid;Password=your_db_password;database=your_db_name"
    providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Your form code goes here

```
public void LoadActivityData
    {
        string cnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstringname"].ConnectionString;

        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(cnString);

        DataSet dsActivity = new DataSet();
        string selectStr = "SELECT * FROM YourActivityTable";

        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectStr, myConn);

        adapter.Fill(dsActivity, "Activities");

        grdView1.DataSource = dsActivity;

    }
```

Use `System.Configuration` namespace to get the configurationmanager class.